# Determine if Commitment control is running

Tags: rpgle, db2-400

I am attempting to conditionally use commitment control.  RPG allows a conditional COMMIT keyword on the files it is opening.  Since one of my programs is called from within a trigger, I want the higher level logic to control the commit scope.  This means, in the trigger, I need to determine if commitment control is in effect, and if so, pass an optional parameter to the called programs.

Does anyone know of a way to tell if commitment control is currently running in RPG or DB2400?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QTNRCMTI API will tell you the current commitment control status.